# The scale is not true

Tags: qgis, layouts, scale

I have an issue with the scale in QGIS. It does not show the true scale. The area is zoomed out more than in the ArcMap, where the scale is correct. Both of the pictures are on A3 with a scale 1:5000 (Black and white from QGIS, Coloured form ArcMap).

Do you know how to fix it, or where can be a problem?

I am just a beginner.

[image: Exported map in 1:5000 in QGIS]

[image: Exported map in 1:5000 in ArcMap]

Comment: Why do you feel that the scale is incorrect? How did you create the scale?

Comment: did you allow for differences in DPI? which projection are you using? if it is EPSG:3857 it is wrong any way

Comment: Did you set the scale in the map view, or in the print layout in QGIS? You can be at 5'000 in the map view, and it will be different in the print layout... you need to set your scale in the print layout.